# canvas tag does not appear after angular 6 migration

Tags: angular, canvas, angular6, angular4-forms

Recently my team has migrated our app from Angular/core cli 4.3.2 to 6.1.10.  tag does not appear on the browser. Code is as below

```
<canvas *ngIf="selectedSWP" class="donut" baseChart [data]="[ device[selectedSWP], (100 - device[selectedSWP]).toFixed(2) ]"
              [colors]="doughnutChartColor" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels" [chartType]="doughnutChartType" [options]="doughnutChartOptions"
              (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: We were using angular2-qrscanner version 1.0.7. Once we switched to @zxing/ngx-scanner version latest. Problem was resolved.